# Bootstrap4 card-deck-wrapper vs card-group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

The only difference I can see between `class="card-group"` and `class="card-deck-wrapper"` is that `card-deck-wrapper` has margins and `card-group` doesn't.

Q: What am I missing here? What's the determining factor when using `card-deck-wrapper` vs. `card-group`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes indeed the margins are the difference between between these wrapper classes. The docs do tell you this too:

> Use card groups (`card-group`) to render cards as a single, attached element with equal width and height columns.
>
> Need a set of equal width and height cards that aren’t attached to one another? Use card decks (`card-deck-wrapper`).

So use `card-deck-wrapper` when you need some space between your cards. The  `card-deck-wrapper` class sets a negative `margin` to `undo` the border on the left and right side of the `display:table` with `border-spacing: 1.25rem 0px;` set by the `card-deck` class.

Comment: @ass Jobsen Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568601/how-can-i-add-link-in-the-card-deck-groups