# How can I add link in the card deck groups?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, vue-component

I get reference from here : https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/card/#card-deck-groups

The script like this :

```
<div>
    <b-card-group deck>
        <b-card title="Title"
                img-src="https://picsum.photos/300/300/?image=41"
                img-alt="Img"
                img-top>
            <p class="card-text">
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a
                natural lead-in to additional content. This content
                is a little bit longer.
            </p>
            <div slot="footer">
                <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
            </div>
        </b-card>
        <b-card title="Title"
                img-src="https://picsum.photos/300/300/?image=41"
                img-alt="Img"
                img-top>
            <p class="card-text">
                This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in
                to additional content.
            </p>
            <div slot="footer">
                <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
            </div>
        </b-card>
        <b-card title="Title"
                img-src="https://picsum.photos/300/300/?image=41"
                img-alt="Img"
                img-top>
            <p class="card-text">
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural
                lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content
                than the first to show that equal height action.
            </p>
            <div slot="footer">
                <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
            </div>
        </b-card>
    </b-card-group>
</div>
```

I want to add link in the title and  image

How can I do it?

Comment: what do you mean by a link ? i undersatnd that when you click on image or title you will redirected to another page?

Comment: @boussadjra brahim yes,  that's what I mean

Comment: you could wrap your `b-card` tag with anchor element `<a href="someurl"> <b-card>....</b-card></a>`

Comment: @boussadjra brahim I just want to provide a link in the title and image. Not all

Comment: ok what do mean by ' But the cursor style change to links without href '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the title attribute from the `b-card` and just use a `b-link` inside a `b-card-body` instead...

```
<b-card img-src="https://picsum.photos/300/300/?image=41"
    img-alt="Img"
    img-top
  >
  <b-card-body>
    <b-link to="/">
      Title
    </b-link>
    <p class="card-text">
       This is a wider card with supporting text below as a
       natural lead-in to additional content. This content
       is a little bit longer.
   </p>
  </b-card-body>
</b-card>
```

Comment: Maybe you can help me again. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52651862/how-can-i-make-slider-in-the-card-deck-group-on-the-bootstrap-vue